# whether package-lock.json not contains devDependencies packages in package.json?

Tags: npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json

As title. I have some packages which only used when I develop. Therefore, I put these packages in devDependencies in package.json

Then when I use `npm install --production`, and there is no package which in devDependencies in `node_modules`.. BUT still will show packages in devDependencies in package-lock.json.

Any idea I can remove these packages in devDependencies in package-lock.json? thanks!!